# Insert data into the database

Tags: nodes

I try to save some data I get into a form in the database but I don't know how to do it.

Currently, here is what I have in the database (I try to add articles). As you can see I already have 2 of them but I set them using directly the CMS.
Now I would like to be able to modify these data (for exemple the title of an article) and even add new full articles if possible.

[image: records]

To get the articles this is what I am doing (it works).

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $query->condition('type', 'Article');
    $items_ids = $query->execute();
    $items = Node::loadMultiple($items_ids);
```

How do I set the title for the article 2 to *title 2 changed*?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! On the duplicated question, there is an explicit answer about titles, if that is more important for you.

Comment: Thanks looks like this is what I was looking for. Sorry I'm new to drupal, I would like to extends the question, but it's not really code related I guess. I would like to know if all "entities" are necessarly represented by node. If there is an entity which isn't stored in node I guess we will update with differents methods than the node ones.

Comment: @Minirock Nodes are one of Drupal's entity types, users and taxonomy terms are entities as well. It is also possible to create custom entity types, but that can be quite a complicated task if you are new to Drupal :)

Comment: I guess then it makes most of the time more sense to create a new content type (like article) in a node rather than creating a new entity type like node directly ? It's just a little bit confusing to consider all the logic will finally be stored in nodes table.